# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [French Language Stack Exchange](http://french.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://french.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [« Ce qui se passe » ou « ce qu'il se passe » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9029/ce-qui-se-passe-ou-ce-quil-se-passe)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Peut-on « être les yeux bleus » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/peut-on-etre-les-yeux-bleus)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Comment utiliser le passé composé et l'imparfait en présence d'une indication de temps supplémentaire ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8901/comment-utiliser-le-passe-compose-et-limparfait)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Quel est le sens de « voter » utilisé de façon transitive ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/quel-est-le-sens-de-voter-utilise-de-facon-transitive)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Quelle est la différence entre « petits » et « petites » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8833/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-petits-et-petites)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Double past participle / passé antérieur](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8842/double-past-participle-passe-anterieur)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Peut-on personnifier un fleuve en français ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9041/peut-on-personnifier-un-fleuve-en-francais)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What is the meaning of “la/une majorité” with “de” or “des”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8942/what-is-the-meaning-of-la-une-majorite-with-de-or-des)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Sentence inversion for questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/sentence-inversion-for-questions)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [« Savoir ce que vous parlez » ou « savoir de quoi vous parlez » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8811/savoir-ce-que-vous-parlez-ou-savoir-de-quoivous-parlez)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 4)

---